# Obrigar usuário a marcar taxonomia customizada no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Pessoal gostaria de saber se tem como obrigar o usuário a marcar pelo menos uma taxonomia customizada no WordPress?
Ex: Em um post tenho taxonomias customizadas, gostaria de obrigar o usuário quando estivesse inserindo o post marcar pelo menos uma categoria.

Comment: Mateus, [corrigi um bug no código](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/32604/revisions), são só duas linhas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta é uma clássica no WPSE: [*Force category choice before creating new post?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/14403/12615)

É necessário adaptar o `post_type`, adicionar a taxonomia customizada em [`wp_dropdown_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) e usar a função [`wp_set_object_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) para atualizar essa taxonomia.

Adaptei usando `portfolio` como Post Type e `location` como Custom Taxonomy. Quando clicamos em <kbd>Adicionar novo</kbd>, aparece primeiro uma tela pedindo a seleção de uma categoria, ao selecionar e enviar o novo post é criado com a categoria personalizada selecionada. A consideração é que isso só é necessário ao criar um novo post, se for para controlar as seleções de posts existentes é necessário injetar jQuery para isso.

```
# Adapted from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/force-category-choice-before-creating-new-post
add_filter( 'load-post-new.php', 'wpse14403_load_post_new' );
function wpse14403_load_post_new()
{
    $post_type = 'portfolio';
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ) {
        $post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];
    }
    else
        return; // Se o post_type for 'post', o REQUEST vem vazio, precisa disto para não disparar nos posts

    // Only do this for posts
    if ( 'portfolio' != $post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( array_key_exists( 'category_id', $_REQUEST ) ) {
        add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse14403_wp_insert_post' );
        return;
    }

    // Show intermediate screen
    extract( $GLOBALS );
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
    $title = $post_type_object->labels->add_new_item;

    include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php' );

    $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( array(
        'name' => 'category_id',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
        'echo' => false,
    ) );

    $category_label = __( 'Category:' );
    $continue_label = __( 'Continue' );
    echo <<<HTML
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>{$title}</h2>

    <form method="get">
        <table class="form-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">{$category_label}</th>
                    <td>{$dropdown}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <th><input name="continue" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="{$continue_label}" /></th>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="{$post_type}" />
    </form>
</div>
HTML;
    include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-footer.php' );
    exit();
}

// This function will only be called when creating an empty post,
// via `get_default_post_to_edit()`, called in post-new.php
function wpse14403_wp_insert_post( $post_id )
{
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, intval($_REQUEST['category_id']), 'location' );
}
```